# Nodejs redirect return NULL

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress

I am building a WordPress woocommerce payment plugin, and an API inside a Nodejs backend server to connect with.

I am using curl to call API ('https://test.com/test') as normal:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body)
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($result);
```

And then in my API, I have to receive and check POST paramemters, and then redirect to another router ('https://test.com/render) to render an ejs view page.
I tried to use

```
res.redirect(307, 'https://test.com/test')
```

or

```
res.writeHead(307, { 'Location': 'https://test.com/test' });
res.end();
```

or render the page directly

`res.render('index', { merchantUser: UserID });`

or even

```
window.location.href = 'https://test.com/test'
```

But the first three returned NULL directly, and the last one return 'window not defined'. And none of them reaches the redirect router ('https://test.com/render).

Thats all I can find online, could someone help me or give me some advices? Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you show your code for receiving the api where you wanna do the redirection

Comment: @mooga Its in my question, I tried res.redirect(), res.writeHead(), res.render(). Before that I was only collecting the data and check if they are valid.

Answer (score 0):

- I would suggest you wait for the response from the first API of NodeJs and check the response http code, if it is 200 then hit another NodeJs API.
- OR send the response from NodeJs API like this and echo response in php:

  `res.send('<script>window.location.href="your URL";</script>');`
- OR complete your all NodeJs process at once and send an ejs view page (html) as response to php curl request